# Xcode 7 (iOS 9) Communications error: <OS_xpc_error: <error: 0x10a1abb40>

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift, ios9, xcode7

Can any one help me to figure out the following error I get when I run my application?

> ```
> Communications error: <OS_xpc_error: <error: 0x10a1abb40> { count = 1,
> contents = "XPCErrorDescription" => <string: 0x10a1abef0> { length =
> 22, contents = "Connection interrupted" } }>
> ```

Comment: I have the same problem, any one know the answer ?

Comment: i have same issue when i add uitextview on uiview and this error occurred. this problem into iOS9 and later. same code working perfectly into iOS8. any one get any solution ? pls help me for that.

Answer (score 7):

If you are running your app in iOS simulator it uses **XPC Services API** for interprocess communication and any breakpoint or other interruptions can cause such an error.

You can refer to this [Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingXPCServices.html)

In the section **Handling Errors**

> Interruption handler—called when the process on the other end of the connection has crashed or has otherwise closed its connection.

The debugging of app on device should not have such problems.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when running my app and keyboard extension (I'm building a custom keyboard). Since you do not provide enough information we don't know when this happens to you exactly.. so I'll leave this here in case you are working in an extension too, if not.. hope this will be useful to someone else.

- Open the info.plist from your Keyboard Target.
- Set Value "Yes" for key "RequestsOpenAccess"
- Run your App on device
- Go To Settings, General, Keyboard, Keyboards
- Select your keyboard
- Change "Allow Full Access" to True.

Answer (score 0):

Please pay attention how often you are accessing to the Database.
I also have the same problem. I am working with chat using Firebase. So in my case I made a mistake when I too often get/put data from/into DB.